# dlookup function in access

Tags: ms-access

I'm first time trying to use dlookup function in access as below but I get blank output.

```
select dlookup ("quantity","test","series > 2000") from test
```

This is test table

```
 id series  quantity
 1  1000    25
 2  2000    33
 3  3000    44
 4  4000    55
 5  5000    66
 6  6000    77
```

I thought the above query will display all records from the table below which has series more than 2000 i.e. as below but it displays blank result.

```
 id series  quantity
 3  3000    44
 4  4000    55
 5  5000    66
 6  6000    77
```

I'm not sure if my syntax is incorrect or anything else. I already double checked my syntax from various sources though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DLookup()` returns a single value, which is not what I think you want.  Just put your selection constraint in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT id, series, quantity
FROM test
WHERE series > 2000;
```

Comment: Thanks Hansup...I know sql code...but I was trying to use Dlookup Function for the first time.

Comment: I understood now...Thanks...I didn't know Dlookup() just returns a single value. I was expecting all records > 2000 and I thought there was a mistake in my code

Comment: DLookup and the other "domain functions" (DMin, DMax, DAvg, etc.) can be convenient but there are also many situations where they are inappropriate.  Kudos to you for your efforts at ensuring you know the difference.  :-)